# Bash command to List usernames not existing in file A

Tags: compare

File A:-

James

Peter

Mike

Tom

Martha

Jenny

File B:-

James

Becky

Mary

Tania

Maria

Tanny

Shakira

The output should be in a third file:->

File C:-

Becky

Mary

Tania

Maria

Tanny

Shakira

I am unable to find or maybe understand which to use. I try diff and comm but not able to get what i want

Answer (score 0):

Use join -v 2 A B

Note that join, like the other relational commands assumes that all input files are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried running this with your data, but fgrep should work here:

```
fgrep -fA -v B > C
```

You might want to remove blank lines before from A before using it as a pattern file though.